# Android: Menu not shown as normal menu, but as popup menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-actionbar-compat

So i created an app with an activity and mutiple fragments. 
In one fragment i tried to add an menu to it, but this menu is shown as a popup menu with 3 dots and not shown as action item to be clicked immediately(like in a normal menu). The menu icon isn´t shown, too.

Here is my code:

Java:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return view;
}
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.twitter_menu, menu);
    }
```

xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menuitem_getBack" 
        android:title="#rutenfest2014"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText" 
        android:icon="@drawable/twitter_logo" />
</menu>
```

I want the menu to be shown with its icons in the actionbar.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: What is your minimum API version? Are you using the AppCompat action bar?

Comment: My miminum api version is 7 and yes i´m using app compat action bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `android:showAsAction` attribute was not added until API 11.

If you are using anything below API 11 and you are using the AppCompat ActionBar, you need to use a custom namespaced `showAsAction` attribute like so:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/menuitem_getBack" 
        android:title="#rutenfest2014"
        myapp:showAsAction="always|withText" 
        android:icon="@drawable/twitter_logo" />
</menu>
```

For more information, see the [Action Bar: Adding Action Items](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems) documentation.